# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, typeerror, nltk

Ive created this program to auto check words in an essay and offer corrections but I keep getting the above error on the .join call when running it. This is the code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

def autocorrect_essay(essay):
    # Tokenize the essay into sentences and words
    sentences = sent_tokenize(essay)
    corrected_sentences = []
    
    for sentence in sentences:
        words = word_tokenize(sentence)
        corrected_words = []
        
        for word in words:
            # Check if the word is misspelled
            if not wordnet.synsets(word):
                corrected_word = correct_word(word)
                corrected_words.append(corrected_word)
            else:
                corrected_words.append(word)
        
        # Join the corrected words to form a sentence
        corrected_sentence = ' '.join(corrected_words)
        corrected_sentences.append(corrected_sentence)
    
    # Join the corrected sentences to form the final essay
    corrected_essay = ' '.join(corrected_sentences)
    
    return corrected_essay

def correct_word(word):
    # Lemmatize the word to get its base form
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)

    # Find similar words based on Levenshtein distance
    similar_words = []
    
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(lemma):
        for lemma_name in synset.lemma_names():
            similar_words.append(lemma_name)

    # Find the most similar word based on Levenshtein distance
    min_distance = float('inf')
    best_word = None
    
    for similar_word in similar_words:
        distance = nltk.edit_distance(word, similar_word)
        
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            best_word = similar_word
    
    return best_word

# Example usage
essay = "I havv a bigg problm with speling. Plese help me correct my essay."
corrected_essay = autocorrect_essay(essay)
print(corrected_essay)
```

Some things I've tried are removing parts of the block that return empty but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `correct_word` can return None. When that happens, you end up appending None to your list and it breaks things downsteam.

One thing you can do in the case that you can't find any suitable matches at all is to just return the original word.

Something like this works (I changed `best_word = None` to `best_word = word`)

```
def correct_word(word):
    # Lemmatize the word to get its base form
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)

    # Find similar words based on Levenshtein distance
    similar_words = set()
    
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(lemma):
        for lemma_name in synset.lemma_names():
            similar_words.add(lemma_name)

    # Find the most similar word based on Levenshtein distance
    min_distance = float('inf')
    best_word = word  # changed this line to make best_word start off as word instead of None
    
    for similar_word in similar_words:
        distance = nltk.edit_distance(word, similar_word)
        
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            best_word = similar_word
    
    return best_word
```

Comment: I just did this fix and It fixed all of the errors but now it doesn't seem to be working at all. Like the sentence autocorrection just don't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You clearly expect that lemmatizing a misspelled word will give you something you can look up in wordnet; but it doesn't, certainly not for your examples. For example:

```
>>> lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("problm"))
problm
>>> wordnet.synsets("problm")
[]
```

So you don't get any real words resembling the misspelled word. This is not a programming error, it is a problem with your approach. You'll need to go back and think of another way to discover similar words that are in the dictionary.